# What sort of technologies were used to build NoHomophobes.com (real-time keyword tracker for Twitter)?

Tags: web, twitter

Do you think that they plugged directly into the Twitter API, or do they have some sort of backend which is what connects to the Twitter API directly instead? I didn't realize this kind of functionality was available to standard users.

Link: [NoHomophobes.com](http://www.NoHomophobes.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This site](https://www.commarts.com/interactive/cai13/nohomophobes.html) has a (short) piece about the technology used - it does seem like they're using the standard, public API:

> "Using Twitter's API, tweets [...] were pulled, tracked and displayed
> in real time
>
> [...]
>
> We couldn't simply pull every tweet ... A lot of research and testing
> was conducted to determine which words and phrases to capture, as well
> as what parameters the tweets had to follow in order to be funneled
> onto the site"

Also, the site's own [T&C's](http://www.nohomophobes.com/#!/about/) mention

> This website contains a licensed real time display of Tweets

At a guess, they're effectively continually searching for certain terms in public tweets (as any Twitter client can do) and displaying the results.

Comment: Thanks! Any idea what it takes to get that sort of license, or if its even required and _licensed_ just refers to the terms of use of Twitter's standard developer agreement?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the site uses the [Twitter Streaming APIs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis) which allow a persistent connection with Twitter. And as filtered tweets come through, it processes the data and delivers it to website users through web sockets via a 3rd party service called [Pusher](http://pusher.com/).